# Update ignore_above for keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch

Existing mapping:

```
"call": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false,
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
```

The update:

```
PUT myIndex/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "call": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 500
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And I get this error:

```
  {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [call] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [call] has different [norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Mapper for [call] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [call] has different [norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the "norms" property in your update too. You have set this to false in your original mapping. Leaving it out will cause Elasticsearch to try to set it to the default value, which is true. Enabling the norms field after it has been disabled is not possible. You have to create a new index if you want that.

Here is the correct update:

```
PUT myIndex/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "call": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false,
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 500
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```